# how to get metadata and widgets properties from another application using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

I want to get metadata and widgets details about another application. For example in calculator application it will have some text box and buttons events. If I click on add button on calculator, I should get widget id, class, events, etc. details of the add button and from my application I have to pass click event for button using c# hook class. If anyone knows please help me..

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i tried global mouse and keyboard hook concepts but it will show only x and y coordinates number..  i need metadata and widget details.. so now i'm trying reflection now hope it will help me